# CSS applying for code in Chrome, but not in Firefox and IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code snippet which has `CSS` applied to it ... For some reason though, the result shown in Chrome is after the `CSS` is applied, while in Firefox and IE, I think no `CSS` is being applied for some reason ..

I'm sure the reason is something very basic which I seem to be missed. If someone can point it out, I'd be very grateful.

**JSFiddle Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/2NJUs/

Comment: There's some syntax error around your CSS line 65

Comment: Please add some of the code here which you suspect is causing the problem. Should the fiddle go down or expire, the question will still be relevant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the folllowing Js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/ptq6z/

```
  body {
    padding: 1em;
}
body {
    font: normal 62.5% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 120px;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 0px 15px #292929;
    letter-spacing: -7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #DDDDDD;
}
#main_tabs {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 322px;
}
div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
ul, ol {
    color: #777;
}
#main_tabs_nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: 0;
    width: 322px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#main_tabs_nav li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: 0;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn1 a {
    width: 108px;

    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}


#main_tabs_nav li a {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 60px;
    border: 0;
}
a {
    color: #4a6491;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a {
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn2 a {
    width: 102px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") -108px 0 no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn3 a {
    width: 111px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") -210px 0 no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
a.active {
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") 0 -60px no-repeat;
}
li {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.66em;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #777;
}
li {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#main_tabs_repeat {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 322px;
    margin: 57px 0 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_bottom_repeat.png") 0 0 repeat-y;
}
#divleftcontent0, #divleftcontent1, #divleftcontent2 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 322px;
    height: 296px;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
}
#divleftcontent0 h3 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto 20px auto;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 65px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/newsletter_text.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
h3 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    letter-spacing: .04em;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #4a6491;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 3px 0;
}
.tab_sep {
    position: relative;
    height: 6px;
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_sep_line.png") 0 0 repeat-x;
}
#divleftcontent0 p {
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    color: #a2b2c6;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
}
p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.66em;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
tr, th, td {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#news_form {
    position: relative;
    width: 247px;
    margin: 35px auto 0 auto;
}
form {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
fieldset {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
legend {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #93ccdd;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    display: none;
}
#divleftcontent0 input {
    position: relative;
    width: 227px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 5px 8px 6px;
    color: #a4afcb;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_newsletter_tab_field.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#divleftcontent0 button {
    position: relative;
    width: 246px;
    height: 27px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/sprite_btns.png") -149px 0 no-repeat;
}
button {
    padding: 1px 6px;
}
#divleftcontent1 table {
    background: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
table {
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#divleftcontent1 table tr {
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_sep_line.png") 0 bottom repeat-x;
}
tr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#divleftcontent1 table td {
    background: 0;
    border: 0;
}
table td {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dde2e8;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
td {
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#divleftcontent1 table a:hover {
    color: #EF7F25;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#divleftcontent1 table a {
    color: #a2b2c6;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.3em;
}
#divleftcontent1 table a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#social_facebook span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_icons_hp.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#social_twitter span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_icons_hp.png") -31px 0 no-repeat;
}
#social_steepster span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_icons_hp.png") -63px 0 no-repeat;
}
#social_linkedin span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_icons_hp.png") -95px 0 no-repeat;
}
#social_blog span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_icons_hp.png") -127px 0 no-repeat;
}
#social_share span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_icons_hp.png") -159px 0 no-repeat;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn2 a:hover, #main_tabs_nav li.sn2 a.active {
    background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") no-repeat scroll -108px -60px transparent;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn3 a:hover, #main_tabs_nav li.sn3 a.active {
    background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") no-repeat scroll -210px -60px transparent;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn1 a:hover, #main_tabs_nav li.sn1 a.active {
    background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -60px transparent;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn1 a {
    background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 108px;
}
#divleftcontent1 h3 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto 20px auto;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 65px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_text.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#divleftcontent2 .scrollable4 {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 245px;
    height: 290px;
}
#divleftcontent2 div {
    position: relative;
    width: 245px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
#divleftcontent2 .scrollable4 .items {
    width: 20000em;
    position: absolute;
}
#divleftcontent2 .items div {
    float: left;
}
#divleftcontent2 .scrollable4 h3 {
    margin: 0;
}
#divleftcontent2 div h3 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ef7f25;
}
#divleftcontent2 div p {
    position: relative;
    color: #a2b2c6;
}
#divleftcontent2 .scrollablenavi {
    height: 44px;
    width: 322px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -43px;
    z-index: 20;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#divleftcontent2 .scrollablenavi ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
#divleftcontent2 .scrollablenavi li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    background: 0;
}
#divleftcontent2 .browse.left {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 5px 15px 5px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_testimonials_btns.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}
#divleftcontent2 div a {
    position: relative;
    color: #ef7f25;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#divleftcontent2 .browse.right {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    float: right;
    margin: 16px 5px 15px 5px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_testimonials_btns.png") -39px 0 no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}
#main_tabs_bottom {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 322px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 40px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_bottom_bg.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
a {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This with some errors corrected

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/2NJUs/2/)

```
body {
    padding: 1em;
}
body {
    font: normal 62.5% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 120px;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 0px 15px #292929;
    letter-spacing: -7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #DDDDDD;
}
#main_tabs {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 322px;
}
div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
ul, ol {
    color: #777;
}
#main_tabs_nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: 0;
    width: 322px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#main_tabs_nav li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: 0;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn1 a {
    width: 108px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
#main_tabs_nav li a {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 60px;
    border: 0;
}
a {
    color: #4a6491;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a {
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn2 a {
    width: 102px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") -108px 0 no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn3 a {
    width: 111px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") -210px 0 no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
a.active {
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") 0 -60px no-repeat;
}
li {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.66em;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #777;
}
li {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#main_tabs_repeat {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 322px;
    margin: 57px 0 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_bottom_repeat.png") 0 0 repeat-y;
}
#divleftcontent0, #divleftcontent1, #divleftcontent2 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 322px;
    height: 296px;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
}
#divleftcontent0 h3 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto 20px auto;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 65px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/newsletter_text.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
h3 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    letter-spacing: .04em;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #4a6491;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 3px 0;
}
.tab_sep {
    position: relative;
    height: 6px;
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_sep_line.png") 0 0 repeat-x;
}
#divleftcontent0 p {
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    color: #a2b2c6;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
}
p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.66em;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
tr, th, td {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#news_form {
    position: relative;
    width: 247px;
    margin: 35px auto 0 auto;
}
form {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
fieldset {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
legend {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #93ccdd;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    display: none;
}
#divleftcontent0 input {
    position: relative;
    width: 227px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 5px 8px 6px;
    color: #a4afcb;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_newsletter_tab_field.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#divleftcontent0 button {
    position: relative;
    width: 246px;
    height: 27px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/sprite_btns.png") -149px 0 no-repeat;
}
button {
    padding: 1px 6px;
}
#divleftcontent1 table {
    background: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
table {
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#divleftcontent1 table tr {
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_sep_line.png") 0 bottom repeat-x;
}
tr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#divleftcontent1 table td {
    background: 0;
    border: 0;
}
table td {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dde2e8;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
td {
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#divleftcontent1 table a:hover {
    color: #EF7F25;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#divleftcontent1 table a {
    color: #a2b2c6;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.3em;
}
#divleftcontent1 table a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
#social_facebook span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_icons_hp.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#social_twitter span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_icons_hp.png") -31px 0 no-repeat;
}
#social_steepster span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_icons_hp.png") -63px 0 no-repeat;
}
#social_linkedin span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_icons_hp.png") -95px 0 no-repeat;
}
#social_blog span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_icons_hp.png") -127px 0 no-repeat;
}
#social_share span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_icons_hp.png") -159px 0 no-repeat;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn2 a:hover, #main_tabs_nav li.sn2 a.active {
    background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") no-repeat scroll -108px -60px transparent;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn3 a:hover, #main_tabs_nav li.sn3 a.active {
    background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") no-repeat scroll -210px -60px transparent;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn1 a:hover, #main_tabs_nav li.sn1 a.active {
    background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -60px transparent;
}
#main_tabs_nav li.sn1 a {
    background: url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_menu.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 108px;
}
#divleftcontent1 h3 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto 20px auto;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 65px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/social_text.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#divleftcontent2 .scrollable4 {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 245px;
    height: 290px;
}
#divleftcontent2 div {
    position: relative;
    width: 245px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
#divleftcontent2 .scrollable4 .items {
    width: 20000em;
    position: absolute;
}
#divleftcontent2 .items div {
    float: left;
}
#divleftcontent2 .scrollable4 h3 {
    margin: 0;
}
#divleftcontent2 div h3 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #ef7f25;
}
#divleftcontent2 div p {
    position: relative;
    color: #a2b2c6;
}
#divleftcontent2 .scrollablenavi {
    height: 44px;
    width: 322px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -43px;
    z-index: 20;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#divleftcontent2 .scrollablenavi ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
#divleftcontent2 .scrollablenavi li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    background: 0;
}
#divleftcontent2 .browse.left {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 5px 15px 5px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_testimonials_btns.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}
#divleftcontent2 div a {
    position: relative;
    color: #ef7f25;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#divleftcontent2 .browse.right {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    float: right;
    margin: 16px 5px 15px 5px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_testimonials_btns.png") -39px 0 no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}
#main_tabs_bottom {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 322px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 40px;
    background: transparent url("http://www.jenierteas.com/templates/default/images/hp_tabs_bottom_bg.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
a {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding DOCTYPE, the problem on IE is solved successfully. IE might require a hashlayout on the header.
There are some parse errors which do not affect chrome but not so for firefox, which is why the css was  activated in firefox.

Comment: What doctype? Can you please further elaborate your answer?